Polling for fetches with timeout - Message printed Continuosly message in logs after spring boot upgrade to 3.2.4
I have upgraded the Spring boot version in my Application from 3.1.2 to 3.2.4.
Since my upgrade, I have seen the below message logged continuously.
The below message floods the logs and it's frustrating that I'm not able to find actual business log statements while on TRACE mode because the whole log file is swammed with these messages.
Is there anything broken in spring-kafka in the latest version??
Unable to figure it out. Any help is much appreciated.
] [                                                 ] fkaConsumerFactory$ExtendedKafkaConsumer : [Consumer clientId=consumer-**-business-service-5, groupId=**-business-service] Polling for fetches with timeout 721
2024-04-04T00:15:18.320+08:00 TRACE 18596 --- [**-service] [ntainer#1-0-C-1] [                                                 ] fkaConsumerFactory$ExtendedKafkaConsumer : [Consumer clientId=consumer-**-business-service-8, groupId=**-business-service] Polling for fetches with timeout 721
2024-04-04T00:15:18.320+08:00 TRACE 18596 --- [**-service] [ntainer#4-0-C-1] [                                                 ] fkaConsumerFactory$ExtendedKafkaConsumer : [Consumer clientId=consumer-**-business-service-5, groupId=**-business-service] Polling for fetches with timeout 721
2024-04-04T00:15:18.321+08:00 TRACE 18596 --- [**-service] [ntainer#1-0-C-1] [                                                 ] fkaConsumerFactory$ExtendedKafkaConsumer : [Consumer clientId=consumer-**-business-service-8, groupId=**-business-service] Polling for fetches with timeout 721
2024-04-04T00:15:18.321+08:00 TRACE 18596 --- [**-service] [ntainer#4-0-C-1] [                                                 ] fkaConsumerFactory$ExtendedKafkaConsumer : [Consumer clientId=consumer-**-business-service-5, groupId=**-business-service] Polling for fetches with timeout 720
2024-04-04T00:15:18.425+08:00 TRACE 18596 --- [**-service] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] [                                                 ] fkaConsumerFactory$ExtendedKafkaConsumer : [Consumer clientId=consumer-**-business-service-7, groupId=**-business-service] Polling for fetches with timeout 616
2024-04-04T00:15:18.426+08:00 TRACE 18596 --- [**-service] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] [                                                 ] fkaConsumerFactory$ExtendedKafkaConsumer : [Consumer clientId=consumer-**-business-service-7, groupId=**-business-service] Polling for fetches with timeout 615


Is there a small application where we can reproduce it? Also, have you compared the same TRACE settings between 3.1.2 and 3.2.4 and observed that this is occurring only in the latest?

@sobychacko -  currently I don't have any demo/POC application to showcase that.
I have compared the TRACE, the older version doesn't print that.

@sobychacko sample application to replicate the issues can be found here -> https://github.com/cumulate/spring-kafka-issue-continuous-log

See my analysis here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/3179#issuecomment-2038564949
